# How to code @QueryResult class to properly capture cypher result. (Without trial and error)

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

What is the best way to go about defining @QueryResult classes? 
I have defined a repository method annotated with query like

```
"MATCH(p:Person{name:{0}) - [r]-(e)
RETURN distinct label(e) as type ,count(label(e)) as count;"
```

On neo4j console output looks like map.

```
type count
----  -----
Account 2
Document 5
Organization 4
```

So i have defined return type of the method like `Map<String, Long>` but doesn't work. Then I tried other ways - it returns the counts combined not individual. now am planning to use java driver to solve this problem. What the best way to go about designing `@QueryResult` to fit my situation. Any resources will be helpful along with the answer to my problem. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your query should return `count(e)` and not `count(labels(e))`.

You can then use a `org.neo4j.ogm.model.Result` to hold the results of your query :

```
@Query("MATCH(p:Person{lastName:{0}}) -[r]-(e) RETURN distinct labels(e) as type ,count(e) as count")
Result resultExample(String name);
```

Comment: Thanks. what is the best way to map cypher query results into java objects. there are many options out there and mostly focus on spring-data-neo4j that again uses ogm. There is another option using plain java-driver. My use case is  to get query results and pass it to other parts of the application like spring service/controllers then finally expose some JSON endpoints. I'll be writing few complex cypher queries based on specific end point. In spring-data-neo4j , coming up with correct @QueryResult class is always not possible.What is the best way to implement data access layer?

Comment: For exposing entities as json, you can have a look at spring data rest. Generally speaking, SDN/OGM is useful if you need to implement business logic around a domain model that matches your graph data. Otherwise, if you need a lot of custom cypher queries, or manage bulk operations, other options (like using directly the java driver) may be better.

Comment: Using SDN- domains-entities means having fixed set of Domain classes like Employee class. This becomes no-so-flexible approach when the solution needs to work in a client environment where there is no Employee class but Furniture class for example. So better way is to read everything in a generic manner and send as json. In which case SDN is not actually of good help. So java driver is the only life saver in this case?